# When does Github provide auto-merge resolution?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

Background: 
I wrote a script to updating the copyrights on all the files in my team's github repository. There are over a hundred thousand files to update. I'm updating them 1 subdirectory at a time.

My question is, if I make a pull request after updating just the copyrights of ~2,000 files, will github automatically merge these files? I really don't want to have to manually approve each merge conflict, because there will be WAY too many...

Answer (score 2):

If you are the only person who is working on that part with copyrights -
 maybe the header - of these files, there will be an automatic merge, as long as there will be no conflicts (i.e, no one else changing on the same lines in parallel).